# AWS SSM InvalidDocument: Document with name SSM-SessionManagerRunShell does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am unable to get process counters or running processes using AWS SSM managed instance. The error is: Error - Fleet Manager is unable to start the session. InvalidDocument: Document with name SSM-SessionManagerRunShell does not exist.

The interactive session manager works and file system browser works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a transient issue - there is a delay between switching from basic/standard to advanced tiers.